# Storing ajax response array into a variable for later usage

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

Hi I need to store an AJAX Response into two variables x and y or into a array.
My AJAX response is a array. I am able to see the data but only with and alert into che call.
I need the data outside the ajax call

```
var x;
var y;

$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxload.php',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        x = data.posX;
        y = data.posX;
        alert(x + " " + y);  // I can se data but I need outside ajax call
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean `window.x` and `window.y` ?

Comment: this should really work, have you tried alerting outside ajax functions, also you are missing `});` at the very last line, this could be the problem aswell

Comment: ahha sorry I correct  }); missing.  I allready have x e y value, I will get it from database by php.

Comment: Having global variables is usually not the best way to achieve what you want, and in this case will more than likely end up in you using a variable when it has not been initialised, or it contains a value you're not expecting. You should pass `data.PosX` and `data.PosY` into another function you want to execute after the AJAX call completes.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to reuse the ajax response later within your code.
If that's the case, your current code wouldn't work because by default, the javascript engine doesn't wait for the response of ajax requests. In other words the code below won't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x; 
    var y;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxload.php',
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(data) { 
            x= data.posX;
            y= data.posX;
            alert (x+" "+y);  // I can se data but I need outside ajax call
        }
    });
    alert(x+" "+y); // You won't see anything, because this data isn't yet populated. The reason for this is, the "success" function is called when the ajax request has finished (it has received a response).
})
</script>
```

You need to wait for the ajax response. To do that with jQuery you need to slightly modify your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
        url:  'ajaxload.php',
        dataType: "json", 
        async: false
    }).responseText); // This will wait until you get a response from the ajax request.

    // Now you can use data.posX, data.posY later in your code and it will work.
    var x = data.posX;
    var y = data.posY;
    alert(x+" "+y);
    alert(data.posX+" "+data.posY);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If this is what you were looking for, please mark my post as the answer :)

Comment: Thanks man! Finally works! Nothing worked for me, but this does! Thanks!

Comment: Hello just for understanding: I consider AJAX async by nature. Supposing I don't want to use "async: false", so a global variable is the unique solution? Or is there a way to "set" the variable value in another script but run it later. Hope you get what I mean. In my case I have two forms and a variable returned by submitting the first form, has to be used in an hidden input field in the second form. But as you may guess, the second form will be submitted later. Thank you for hinting.

Answer (score 22):

you can store the ajax response in a global array for further use in other javascript function

```
var ajaxResult=[];

$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxload.php',
    async:true,
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(data)
     { 
        ajaxResult.push(data);
     }
  });
});
```

```
otherJsfunc()
 {
  console.log(ajaxResult); 
 }
```

Comment: this should be the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you decalre the variable you can access the value out side of ajax.

eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var x = '';
   var y = '';

   function sendAjax()
   {
        // your ajax call
        x= data.posX;
        y= data.posX;  
   } 
   sendAjax();
</script>
```

if the ajax works good you can acces the variable **x** and **y** globaly

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this code within a document ready handler, your x and y variables are not truly global. Try `window.x=''; window.y='';`